# Laravel: Saving data from multiple groups of radio buttons with diffrent names

Tags: laravel, radio-button, store

I'm absolutely new to laravel and my question is if it's possible to save data into database from multiple group of radio buttons with different names.

My Blade (part of if):

```html
@foreach($pol1 as $meczes)
    <strong>{{ $meczes->mecz }}</strong><br /> 
    <input type="radio" name="s" value="<?php echo $meczes->mecz ?> TYP: 1  KURS: <?php echo $p200 ?>"> <strong>1</strong>  - {{$p200}} 
    <input type="radio" name="s" value="<?php echo $meczes->mecz ?> TYP: X  KURS: <?php echo $p4 ?>"> <strong>X</strong>  - {{$p4}} 
    <input type="radio" name="s" value="<?php echo $meczes->mecz ?> TYP: 2  KURS: <?php echo $p6 ?>"> <strong>2</strong>  - {{$p6}} 
    <input type="radio" name="s" value="<?php echo $meczes->mecz ?> TYP: 10  KURS: <?php echo $p201 ?>"> <strong>10</strong>  - {{$p201}} 
    <input type="radio" name="s" value="<?php echo $meczes->mecz ?> TYP: 02  KURS: <?php echo $p201 ?>"> <strong>02</strong>  - {{$p201}} 
    </br>
@endforeach

@foreach($pol2 as $meczes)    
    <strong>{{ $meczes->mecz }}</strong><br> 
    <input type="radio" name="s1" value="<?php echo $meczes->mecz ?> TYP: 1  KURS: <?php echo $p101 ?>"> <strong>1</strong>  - {{$p101}} 
    <input type="radio" name="s1" value="<?php echo $meczes->mecz ?> TYP: X  KURS: <?php echo $p103 ?>"> <strong>X</strong>  - {{$p103}} 
    <input type="radio" name="s1" value="<?php echo $meczes->mecz ?> TYP: 2  KURS: <?php echo $p204 ?>"> <strong>2</strong>  - {{$p204}} 
    <input type="radio" name="s1" value="<?php echo $meczes->mecz ?> TYP: 10  KURS: <?php echo $p200 ?>"> <strong>10</strong>  - {{$p200}} 
    <input type="radio" name="s1" value="<?php echo $meczes->mecz ?> TYP: 02  KURS: <?php echo $p201 ?>"> <strong>02</strong>  - {{$p201}}  
    </br>
@endforeach

@foreach($pol3 as $meczes)
    <strong>{{ $meczes->mecz }}</strong><br> 
    <input type="radio" name="s2" value="<?php echo $meczes->mecz ?> TYP: 1  KURS: <?php echo $p204 ?>"> <strong>1</strong>  - {{$p204}} 
    <input type="radio" name="s2" value="<?php echo $meczes->mecz ?> TYP: X  KURS: <?php echo $p4 ?>"> <strong>X</strong>  - {{$p4}} 
    <input type="radio" name="s2" value="<?php echo $meczes->mecz ?> TYP: 2  KURS: <?php echo $p201 ?>"> <strong>2</strong>  - {{$p201}} 
    <input type="radio" name="s2" value="<?php echo $meczes->mecz ?> TYP: 10  KURS: <?php echo $p3 ?>"> <strong>10</strong>  - {{$p3}} 
    <input type="radio" name="s2" value="<?php echo $meczes->mecz ?> TYP: 02  KURS: <?php echo $p1 ?>"> <strong>02</strong>  - {{$p1}} 
    </br>
@endforeach
```

**Part of my controller:**

```
if (isset($_POST['s'])) {
    $s=$_POST['s'];
} else {
    $s="1";
} //1

if (isset($_POST['s1'])) {
    $s1=$_POST['s1'];
} else {
    $s1="1";
} //2
```

And my question is how to pass the value of each selected button from group (s,s1, etc) into table , each to new row ( table with just id and value as columns).

My intention is that when user would select one option from 's' group and option from 's1' group the value of those buttons would be sent into database . How should store function be written? Would any loop be helpful?

(Sidenote, I have exactly 35 of those groups of buttons and simply I wanted to save data of them to the database when selected after clicking button).

I know it's a bit complicated but I would be grateful for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than have each radio button having a separate name, you could set each name to be in a grouped array. For example:

```
<input type="radio" name="selections[s2]" value="<?php echo $meczes->mecz ?> TYP: 1  KURS: <?php echo $p204 ?>"> <strong>1</strong>  - {{$p204}}
```

When your form is submitted, this will set requests `selections` array key/value.

From then, you could loop through each selection and save to your model (if using eloquent):

```
foreach (request('selections') as $key => $value) {
    Model::create([
        'key' => $key,
        'value' => $value
    ]);
}
```

This answer is to explain the principal of how to achieve this and not the definitive answer (as I don't know your application structure). There may be some relationships involved.

I hope this helps.